# Unable to login to an app on Browserstack

Tags: android, browserstack

Trying to login to an app using browserstack, but receive an error.  The same error does not occur when using an actual phone.  Here are the logs:

07-08 14:51:44.091 D/SoLoader(30206): adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
07-08 14:51:44.091 D/SoLoader(30206): adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main flags = 1]
07-08 14:51:44.091 D/SoLoader(30206): Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
07-08 14:51:44.091 D/SoLoader(30206): Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main flags = 1]
07-08 14:51:44.128 D/SoLoader(30206): libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:44.128 D/SoLoader(30206): libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
07-08 14:51:44.149 D/vulkan  (30206): searching for layers in '/data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64'
07-08 14:51:44.149 D/vulkan  (30206): searching for layers in '/data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a'
07-08 14:51:44.255 D/SoLoader(30206): libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:44.255 D/SoLoader(30206): libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
07-08 14:51:44.257 D/SoLoader(30206): libfbjni.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:44.257 D/SoLoader(30206): libfbjni.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
07-08 14:51:44.260 I/MSHandlerLifeCycle(30206): isMultiSplitHandlerRequested: ignored. pkg=com.vans.vansfamily parent=null callers=com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.setVisibility:4295 android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity:5301 android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute:54 android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute:45 android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState:176
07-08 14:51:44.330 I/vans.vansfamil(30206): [HIDL_FETCH_IMapper] android.hardware.graphics.mapper@4.0: Loaded Mapper successfully.
07-08 14:51:44.334 I/FA      (30206):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.vans.vansfamily
07-08 14:51:44.556 D/SoLoader(30206): libyoga.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:44.556 D/SoLoader(30206): libyoga.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
07-08 14:51:44.612 W/vans.vansfamil(30206): Long monitor contention with owner pool-24-thread-1 (30365) at void com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.f.a(com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.e)(:-1) waiters=0 in void com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.f.a(com.salesforce.marketingcloud.c.e) for 110ms
07-08 14:51:45.030 D/SoLoader(30206): libreactnativeblob.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:45.030 D/SoLoader(30206): libreactnativeblob.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
07-08 14:51:45.463 D/SoLoader(30206): libimagepipeline.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:45.463 D/SoLoader(30206): libimagepipeline.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
07-08 14:51:45.466 D/SoLoader(30206): libgifimage.so not found on /data/data/com.vans.vansfamily/lib-main
07-08 14:51:45.467 D/SoLoader(30206): libgifimage.so found on /data/app/~~XiTSr1w4Ai3eH23IIy1bSg==/com.vans.vansfamily-4s8vZWshdhF4-GTTTyjgjw==/lib/arm64
Load NextSk

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error it seems you are missing some important libraries in your automation project.

I suggest you start your automation using some GitHub repo code for fewer chances of error.

Importantly, please try the same code on your local setup before trying your automation on any cloud-based service.

Could you please specify your tech stack for this automation project and the script you are using to automate app login? It will help others to understand your issue better.